# $window.focus() doesn't work on existing tabs in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari

When I open a new window with `var win = window.open("", "name")` and then focus the window using `win.focus()` this works for the first time in iOS Safari.

But when the existing window is referenced again by name using window.open I can't focus again in iOS Safari. In Chrome this works fine.

Is there any way how I can focus on an already existing tab just knowing the name?

I created a fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/szqnu38f/

Comment: This also works fine in macOS Safari. But I also have this issue in iOS safari

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug within iOS Safari.

Generally, it is not possible to set the focus again on an existing named tab. This is also the case when a link with target set to a name is clicked again after the tab was opened --> see https://jsfiddle.net/g3bk1v5a/4/

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="test">Test</a>
```

Therefore, I opened a bug report at Apple.

Comment: bug or purposeful limitation? who knows with Safari! Can you post a link to your bug report?

Comment: I don't know if you can see the report but it is located here https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/6103465

Answer (score 0):

Until the bug is fixed by Apple, you may use the following workaround:

```
// replace win.focus() by:
win.close();
win = win.open("", "name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if active tab loses focus and reuse open window when possible:

```js
const references = {};

const openReference = (href) => {
  references[href] = open(href, href);
  if (!references[href]) return;

  references[href].addEventListener('load', () => {
    references[href].addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      delete references[href];
    });
  });
};

const handleNoBlur = (callback) => {
  let blurTimeout;

  const handleBlur = () => {
    clearTimeout(blurTimeout);
    removeEventListener('blur', handleBlur);
  };

  blurTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    removeEventListener('blur', handleBlur);

    callback();
  }, 100);

  addEventListener('blur', handleBlur);
};

const openOrFocus = (href) => {
  const reference = references[href];

  if (reference && reference.closed === false) {
    handleNoBlur(() => {
      reference.close();
      openReference(href);
    });

    reference.focus();
  } else {
    openReference(href);
  }
};

openOrFocus('https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem please try to provide a little more insight into your solution to help others understand what you did.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).