# window.focus() does not work for existing tabs in ALL IOS browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I'm trying to create a "re-launch" button that should bring the user to an existing opened tab. So far, this is how it's implemented:

Using `window.open()` initially to create the tab and focusing to that tab using `window.focus()`.

The relaunch button should basically call window.focus() and redirect to that tab.

This has been asked in `$window.focus()` doesn't work on existing tabs in iOS Safari but I'd like to get a more general overview on this question. I've looked everywhere but I couldn't find any lead to this question.

Apparently, it works in android browsers but I can't get it to work in ios browsers (safari, chrome). Does anyone have any clue about this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$window.focus() doesn't work on existing tabs in iOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276312/window-focus-doesnt-work-on-existing-tabs-in-ios-safari)

Comment: No it doesn’t work as well in chrome, you can try by visiting this link https://jsfiddle.net/szqnu38f/  in either mobile safari or chrome

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in iOS browsers. As a workaround you may replace
`focus()` by a sequence of `close()` and `open(...)`.